# sql query that gives the column that have these two word 'fever' and 'temperature'

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzEcK.png)

I tried this but gives a wrong why ??

```
Select patient_id , start_date , reason 
from treatment
where start_date > '2006-12-05' and contains(reason ,'fever' ,'temperature')
```

the error in contains ??

Answer (score 2):

Contains is not a MySQL Operator. But if you want match both the words in same row column you could use like

```
Select patient_id , start_date , reason 
from treatment
where start_date > '2006-12-05' 
and reason like '%fever%' and reason like '%temperature%'
```

if you want almost one of the matching word  you should use OR condition:

```
Select patient_id , start_date , reason 
from treatment
where start_date > '2006-12-05' 
and (reason like '%fever%' OR reason like '%temperature%')
```

Comment: Almost. There should be OR in the WHERE condition.

Comment: @MartinS   i like in my answer  if the OP seach for both word in the same sentence is an and relation .. or relation is if the OP search for almost one od the two word

Comment: Still not 100%, I added the parenthesis to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You should you the `LIKE` keyword instead.

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT  patient_id
      , start_date
      , reason
FROM    treatment
WHERE   start_date > '2006-12-05' AND
        ( reason LIKE '%fever%' OR
          reason LIKE '%temperature%' );
```

Another thing worth mentioning is that depending on the collation of your database, it *could* be case sensitive. So you may need to capitalize everything or lowercase the entire column.

Comment: @manao Please mark my answer as the solution if it solved your problem